# Vba Formula R1C1 help need

Tags: excel, vba, lookup

I would like to use the r1c1 formula to do a lookup for the values in column AF from the current workbook (cbook) and compare that to the values in the prior workbook (pbook).  I am using r1c1 because it is quicker, but am open to other methods.

I would like to copy the values from columns AG, AH, AI and AJ.  I have done research to create the correct code, but and struggling with the range and address (Srng.Address) as well as adding the name of the worksheet to the variable.

Srng is the path and filename of the prior workbook, but the .Address give the cell where the variable exists.  (I have a variable workbook (InstVariable) and the cell is in C28, but I need the string value).  I have tried with many unsuccessful attempts to define the Srang, which is the path with Worksheet name of the prior workbook.  The worksheet should be the name of the current workbook.

Here is part of my code below.  Any help is appreciated!

```
 'Current List Template
    Dim cbook As Workbook
    Set cbook = ActiveWorkbook


    'Prior List Template
    Dim pbook As Workbook
    'Workbook
   ' Set pbook = Workbooks.Open(JRDCPriorNoBrk)

    cbook.Activate


    '********************
    'Turns off screen updates (no flashes)
    '********************
    With Application
        '.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With




    'Make sure user is on JobReq & DataChg INST tab to run macro
    Sheets("JobReq & DataChg INST").Activate


    'unshare the workbook to run macro
    'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.FullName, accessmode:=xlExclusive
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ' ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess


For Each xworksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    xworksheet.Activate

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Original" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "JobReq & DataChg INST" Then GoTo NotThisSheet

    'unprotects sheets so user can run macro
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect


    'ActiveSheet.Range("AG2").Select

    Dim Srng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    'Set Srng = Worksheets("Coniguration").Range("_Configuration")
    'Set Srng = ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AJ18")

    'pbook.Worksheet (cbook.ActiveSheet.Name)
     'LastRowp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row


     'Set Srng = pbook.Worksheet(ActiveSheet.Name)
     'Set Srng = PathJRDCPrior.ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AJ" & LastRowp)





    With ActiveSheet


     'With pbook.Worksheets(cbook.ActiveSheet.Name)
    'With Worksheets(" & PathJRDCPrior & ")
        'current worksheet last row
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row

        'prior worksheet last row
        'MsgBox (cbook.ActiveSheet.Name)
        With pbook.Worksheets(cbook.ActiveSheet.Name)
        'pbook.Worksheets (cbook.ActiveSheet.Name)
        LastRowp = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
        SSheet = cbook.ActiveSheet.Name
        Set SPath = PathJRDCPrior

        'Set Srng = PathJRDCPrior.ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AJ" & LastRowp)
        'Srng = pbook.Worksheets(cbook.ActiveSheet.Name).Range("AF2:AJ" & LastRowp)
        Set Srng = Worksheets(SSheet).Range("AF2:AJ" & LastRowp)
        End With
       ' MsgBox (Srng)

        With cbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AG2:AG" & LastRow)
                   With cbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AG2:AG" & LastRow)
            **.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC32," & Srng.Address(, , xlR1C1, True) & ", 2, 0)"**


            .Value = .Value
        End With
        With cbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AH2:AH" & LastRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC32," & Srng.Address(, , xlR1C1, True) & ", 3, 0)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        With cbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AI2:AI" & LastRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC32," & Srng.Address(, , xlR1C1, True) & ", 4, 0)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        With cbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AJ2:AJ" & LastRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC32," & Srng.Address(, , xlR1C1, True) & ", 5, 0)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
           End With

NotThisSheet:
Next xworksheet

'share workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.FullName, accessmode:=xlShared
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox ("Copying from the prior list is complete.")

End Sub
```

Comment: *I am using r1c1 because it is **quicker*** Quicker? What?

Comment: You *really* need to use `Option Explicit` and properly declare all your variables - it's hard to know if `SSheet` is a typo or a variable. Also, try to avoid using so many comments - comments are supposed to increase readability, not hinder it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is difficult to follow. Ignoring the details, seems like you want to:

- Loop through all worksheets (except two) in `cbook`.
- For each worksheet you loop through, you want to perform a few VLOOKUPs between `cbook` and `pbook`.
- and hard code the results of the VLOOKUPs as static values in `cbook`.

Maybe try the below and see how far you get. You will need to change the file paths in the code to match your own.

It's likely my code doesn't do everything you want/yours did. It's also advisable that you **make copies** of your current workbook and previous workbook and have the code refer to those copies when you run it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LookUpRangeInPreviousWorkbook()

    Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
    Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\misc.xlsb") ' If you're putting your VBA code into currentWorkbook and running it from there, then you may as well just use 'Thisworkbook'

    Dim previousWorkbook As Workbook
    Set previousWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\lol.xlsb") ' JRDCPriorNoBrk is not assigned anywhere in your code, hence it's not assigned anywhere in mine.

    Dim sheetsToSkip As Variant
    sheetsToSkip = Array("Original", "JobReq & DataChg INST")

    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet ' The worksheet from the current workbook that is being looped over. Make the variable name better if possible.

    For Each currentSheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(currentSheet.Name, sheetsToSkip, 0)) Then

            'unprotects sheets so user can run macro
            currentSheet.Unprotect

            With previousWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheet.Name) ' This will throw an error if the previous workbook does not contain the current sheet in the current workbook
                Dim lastRowInPreviousWorkbook As Long
                lastRowInPreviousWorkbook = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row

                Dim rangeAddressFromPreviousWorkbook As String ' This doesn't change below, so just assign it once here.
                rangeAddressFromPreviousWorkbook = .Range("AF2:AJ" & lastRowInPreviousWorkbook).Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, External:=True)
            End With

            With currentSheet
                Dim lastRowInCurrentWorkbook As Long
                lastRowInCurrentWorkbook = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row

                With .Range("AG2:AG" & lastRowInCurrentWorkbook)
                    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AF2," & rangeAddressFromPreviousWorkbook & ", 2, 0)"
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                With .Range("AH2:AH" & lastRowInCurrentWorkbook)
                    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AF2," & rangeAddressFromPreviousWorkbook & ", 3, 0)"
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                With .Range("AI2:AI" & lastRowInCurrentWorkbook)
                    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AF2," & rangeAddressFromPreviousWorkbook & ", 4, 0)"
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                With .Range("AJ2:AJ" & lastRowInCurrentWorkbook)
                    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AF2," & rangeAddressFromPreviousWorkbook & ", 5, 0)"
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
            End With

            ' Do you need re-protect the sheet now? Loop proceeds to next sheet in a few lines.
        End If
    Next currentSheet

    ' You might need to save either/both files -- or do something of that nature here.

    MsgBox ("Copying from the prior list is complete.")

End Sub
```